# Solr : How to create new document

Tags: solr

Well I am writing a custom request handler and  want to create solr document. I have few fields and their values, I want to create a new document with these field and put in doclist and then stuffing doclist(or SolrDocumentList) in response object to send back to client.

how can I do it ??

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well May be I got the answer.

```
 Step 1: Create object of SolrDocumentList 
 Step 2: Create document and add field by calling "add" method
 Step 3: call "add" method using object of SolrDocumentList to add solrDocument because SolrDocumentList  class extends ArrayList<SolrDocument> class.
```

and thats it

Answer (score 0):

Create an instance of SolrInputDocument and add all the field values of the to the document using addField() method.

```
SolrInputDocument doc = new SolrInputDocument();
doc.addField("fieldName", fieldValue);
```